# What hypotheses do I need to add to prove that, The closure of a positive Lebesgue measure set contains an open set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, cantor-set

I know that the fat Cantor set is a counterexample to the above statement, but I would like to know if there is any hypothesis I could add to make this statement valid.

Comment: A set whose closure doesn't contain any open sets is called *nowhere dense*. You may be interested in the Wikipedia article on this term.

Comment: The fat Cantor set is closed, had positive measure but is nowhere dense.

Comment: Let $\Bbb Q=\{q_n:n\in\Bbb N\}.$ Let $A=\cup_{n\in\Bbb N}(q-2^{-n},q+2^{-n}).$ Then $m(A)\le\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}2^{1-n}=2.$ So $m(\Bbb R\setminus A)=\infty.$  The closed set $\Bbb R\setminus A$ has no non-empty open subset because any non-empty open set contains rationals, but $\Bbb R\setminus A$ contains no rationals.